# What happens to the votes given to an answer, if the answer is undeleted after months?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers

Suppose an answer that was voted (up-voted and/or down-voted) is deleted, and undeleted after months. When it is deleted, any reputation change because that answer is removed. What happens when the answer is undeleted?

Comment: the reputation changes according deletion/undeletion of the answer(upvoted/downvote)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The votes still exist while the post is deleted (unless it is hard-deleted, which is rare, and in that case it can't be undeleted anyway), they just don't count for reputation. Once the post is undeleted, the votes are *still* still there, and they count for reputation once again.

Source: I recently discoved an answer of mine I had deleted and forgotten about, saw no real reason for it to be deleted (except maybe to get the Disciplined badge), and undeleted it. Shortly thereafter, I got an unexplained +30 (no +30 in rep log, likely the -30 from the delete just disappeared).

Comment: Did you check the __[ ] Show deleted posts__ box? The undelete points should show up. For a while at least.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference. Probably because the post is not currently deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The reputation changes related to the votes will be restored.

Votes on answers do not decay with time (as e.g. close votes do).